# I'm struggling with SDL2 installation on Xcode 6

Tags: c, xcode6, sdl-2

I'm working on a little project and I'm trying to use SDL2 library! I installed the SDL2.framework successfully in my library/framework folder. Then when I tried to link my headers and my framework in Xcode by adding the Library/Framework path for the framework and /Library/Framework/SDL2.framework/Headers for the headers in my app settings! Then I include
.   #include  
Afterward when I run the program there is an error but not about the fact it doesn't find headers.

Do you guys have a few tips about this?

Thank you
PS : sorry for the eventual English mistake

edit: i finally manage to run the program (i forgot to link binary) but now Xcode shut down right after it

Comment: Explain what the error looks like instead of what it doesn't look like

Comment: In the screenshot it looks like you have not told the linker to link the SDL2 libs, alternatively where to find them.

Comment: Do you mean in my app settings? or the include? Here is what i get : 
/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers for the Header Search Path.
/Library/Frameworks for the Framework Search Path
None for the Library Search Path.

Comment: SDL2 consists of headers and libs (alternatively full source). You have managed to configure where the headers are. The **compiler** finds them. However, the **linker** does not find the libs - hence the undefined references.

Comment: I can clearly see where the problem comes from now! Thank you. But it may seems easy but as a Xcode beginner, i don't have a clue how to solve this..

Answer (score 1):

I finally could install it for those who are struggling with this ! 
 1. Download SDL2 source code on the website.
 2. Compile the framework and copy SDL2.framework in the Library/Framework directory.
 3. Create a classic Xcode project in C. In build settings. Then in Build Phases add SDL2.framework in the "Link binary with libraries" Indicate for the headers search paths : Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers and Library/Frameworks for the framework search paths.

Hope this can help some of you.
Thank you all for the help !

Answer (score 0):

try the following tutorial to see if it helps - http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-in-xcode-osx/

Comment: Thank you for your time ! I did manage to realise your tutorial, but i have two problems. The first is that i would like to use it in C and the second one that when i run your template, it compiles but Xcode shut down right after !